# Time Machine: What files and folders are affected when excluding System Files and Applications?

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup

When you put System Files and Applications in the exclusion list, it is not clear what specific files and folders are being concerned.

Is it just the `/Applications` and `/System` folders?

Are `/private` or `/opt` also excluded? How about `/Library`?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/172216/what-according-to-time-machine-are-system-files-and-applications.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18849?locale=en_US)

> OS X system files include the System folder and the apps that come with your Mac, such as Safari, Mail, Messages, iTunes, Dashboard, and others.

I'd also like to see a complete list. Based on my own testing (on 10.11.1) I can confirm that `/opt` is not included and that not everything in `/Applications` is excluded.